# how to make the dots responsive in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have created a education section as following

[image: In Full Screen]

CSS for the above section is

education-container is containing all contents, education-box is used for the boxes, education-divider is the line dividing the boxes and education-traveler is used for the plane

```
.education-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px; 
    width: 70%;
}

.education-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    min-height: 170px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px  #2857a4;
}  

.education-box:nth-child(2n){
    left: 90%;
}

.education-box:nth-child(2n+1)::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0.8rem;
    width: 0.8rem;
    right: -37%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
}


.education-box:nth-child(2n)::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0.8rem;
    width: 0.8rem;
    left: -40%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
    
}
.education-divider{
    position: absolute;
    border: 2.5px dashed black;
    width: 0;
    height: 80%;
    left: 70%;
    top: 10%;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.education-traveller{
    position: sticky;   
    top: 25%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: orangered;
    
}
```

But as soon as I decrease the screen size the dots get shifted from its position
[image: After decreasing the screen size]

Can anyone suggest me how can I align the dots so that it remains in the same line for all screen size ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2):

Try making all those elements relative to the center and then offset them by pixels.

For example:

Instead of saying `left: 40%`, replace it with `left: calc(50% - 16px)` or whatever the amount of pixels you need. Repeat that for others and they should stay in the same place whatever the screen size is.